# Install MSI with XML Properties File

Tags: powershell, batch-file, wix, installation, windows-installer

Would be grateful to any assistance on how I can install an MSI and modify its default property values through an xml file that has the new values to be inserted during install time. The new property values will then be passed into MSIEXEC as a parameter by referencing the xml file and will therefore look like this:

msiexec /I MyMSIFle.msi PROPERTIESFILE=ProdProperties.xml

The need for this is because we have a number of environments. For sake of argument let's say DEV, TEST and PROD. The MSI property values differ for each environment and will be held in discrete XML properties files, e.g. DEV-Properties.xml, TEST-Properties.xml and PROD-Properties.xml.

The MSI is a single, generic MSI that we intend to install across all three environments successfully, simply by passing in the correct property values, all embedded within the individual XML files.

I'll be particularly happy to accept solutions using Powershell, Windows Batch scripts, VBScript, etc, but no third-party software as we have strict restrictions on using any such products within my company.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an custom action for your MSI. Here is an example how:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2009/05/15/from-msi-to-wix-part-22-dll-custom-actions-introduction.aspx

You could pass the .xml file name as an property and deserialize the file from the given path to an object. From the object you could then override some more properties.

Anyhow I think it is not sensible to contain such logic in an installer. I think a better way would be to write a simple flag to registry telling what environment is in question and the let the installed program deduce rest.